# Looping and Extracting values from HTML

Tags: c#, html, browser

So, I'm just trying to make alittle program for myself to check the status of my Amazon orders. So I handled logining in through a webbrowser, now I was just wondering though about getting titles of the orders through the HTML of it?

An example of an order is this:

```
<SPAN class=item-title>NCAA Oregon Collectible Mini Football Helmet </SPAN>
```

I understand what I have to do, but I don't know exactly how to do so. I know that I have to loop through all the HTML for this class, then extract the text from it. Now I don't know if this is possible to loop, then extract it using the `.InnerText()` method from the Webbrowser or if I would have to use something like Regular Expressions (Which I really am not very well read up on).

So I was wondering if someone could show me a way that you could go about doing this?

What I tried so far (even though it's not much) is something like:

> ```
> HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
> HtmlElementCollection col = doc.GetElementsByTagName("span");
>     foreach (HtmlElement element in col) {
>              string x = element.GetAttribute("class");
>              if (x == "item-title") {
>                  MessageBox.Show(x); //To see if it worked
>               }
>     }
> ```

Comment: HTML is not a regular language, so regular expressions wont work.  You might try taking a look at [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)

Comment: Ahh, Got it! Thank you for the suggestion.
For anyone who reads this I used this article: https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/431250